# A better statment for "Get back to me"

Tags: expressions

I would like to know if there is a better statement for expressing the following statement in an email, "Please get back to me if you have any query".

Comment: There are literally hundreds. This question is too broad for the main site, but if you stick around to get 20 rep points, you can take it to chat.

Answer (score 4):

> Please don't hesitate to contact me if you have any queries.

should work quite well, it's a little more formal.

Comment: Please note, *queries* will only work here in British English.  In American English, you'll want *questions* instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions."

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> "If you have any doubts, please feel free to contact me."

Answer (score -1):

"I welcome any questions you may have."